# Primitive roots and indices

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the congruence $x^3 \equiv a$ (mod p), where $p \geq 5$ is a prime and gcd($a,p$)=1, prove the following

a. If $p \equiv 1$ (mod 6), then the congruence has either no solutions or three incongruent solutions modulo p.

b.If $p \equiv 5$ (mod 6), then the congruence has a unique solution modulo p.

How to solve it...by using the theory of indices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.  Write $x\equiv g^X$ and $a\equiv g^A\pmod p$.  (That is, $x$ has index $X$ and $a$ has index $A$.)  Then the congruence is equivalent to
$$3X\equiv A\pmod{p-1}\ .$$

- If $p\equiv5\pmod6$ then $\gcd(3,p-1)=1$ and so the congruence has a unique solution.
- If $p\equiv1\pmod6$ then $\gcd(3,p-1)=3$ and so the congruence has three solutions (if $A$ is a multiple of $3$) or none (if not).